# Custom ScrollView scrolls to top when a View is added

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I am using a custom View by Matt Clark called [TwoDScrollView](http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview/). It allows me to have vertical and horizontal scrolling.

TwoDScrollView has a child RelativeLayout which is the Scrollable layout.

The problem is that when I add a View to the RelativeLayout programmatically, the TwoDScrollView scrolls to top.

Apparently, this also happens on ScrollViews when a RelativeLayout is used so it is not only from TwoDScrollView.

XML:

```
<com.example.viewmover.TwoDScrollView
    android:id="@+id/twoDScrollView1"
    android:drawingCacheQuality="low" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
         android:id="@+id/scene_container"
         android:drawingCacheQuality="low" 
         android:layout_width="1000dip" 
         android:layout_height="3000dip"
         android:background="@drawable/tiledbackground">

    </RelativeLayout>

</com.example.viewmover.TwoDScrollView>
```

Any ideas of how to solve this problem?